# Creating new table in octobercms

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I must create new table in octobercms project and I followed documentation and added new migration file inside  plugin update file I have create_currency_rates_table.php file and it has this codes

```
<?php namespace RainLab\User\Updates;
use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class CreateCurrencyRateTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currency_rates', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('currency');
         
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('currency_rate');
    }
}
```

when I used php artisan october:up it is not detecting new migration. How can I create new table?Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried just typing php artisan migrate?

Comment: I tried but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to update `plugins\<author>\<plugin_name>\updates\version.yaml` this file and add your file name there as well.

So, in your case, you added a file like `create_currency_rates_table.php` then you need to add details of your file in `version.yaml`

for ex:

```
1.0.1: First version of Demo
1.0.2:
  - Description About what is this update about?
  - create_currency_rates_table.php
```

now when you next time just `login to backend` this table will be created automatically.

if any doubt please comment.